# Question regarding essential singular point of a function

Tags: complex-analysis

How to prove the function $$ f(z)=\exp\Big(\frac{z}{1-\cos z}\Big)$$ has an essential singularity at $z=0$ ?

It's actually hard to express the Laurent series of $f(z)$ around $0$, because the power $\frac{z}{1-\cos z}$ itself is already in the series form (since $\cos z$ appears there and it has the series expansion) and $e^{z/(1-\cos z)}$ has again a series form.

How to Proceed?

Answer (score 1):

We can write

$$\frac{z}{1-\cos(z)}=\left(\frac{z^2}{1-\cos(z)}\right)\,\frac{1}{z}$$

Note that $\frac{z^2}{1-\cos(z)}$ has a removable discontinuity at $z=0$ and once removed, is holomorphic.  Then, we have

$$e^{\frac{z}{1-\cos(z)}}=\underbrace{e^{\frac{z^2}{1-\cos(z)}}}_{\text{Holomorphic}}\,e^{1/z}$$

Since $e^{1/z}=\sum_{n=-\infty}^0 \frac{z^n}{n!}$ has an essential singularity at $z=0$, $e^{\frac{z}{1-\cos(z)}}$ does likewise.

Comment: Please let me know how I can improve my answer. I really want to give you the best answer I can